# Why does $(s_t)$ converge to $s_0$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, compactness, proof-explanation

The following lemma and proof can be found in the book 'Isometries on Banach spaces: Function Spaces' by Fleming and Jamison.

Let $Q$ be a compact metric space. 
Denote $C(Q)$ to be the set of real-valued continuous functions $f$ on $Q,$ endowed with supremum norm $\| f \|_{\infty} = \sup_{s \in Q}|f(s)|.$

> Let $f \in C(Q)$ and $s_0 \in Q$ such that $\| f \|_{\infty} =
>  |f(s_0)|.$ Then $|f(s_0)| > |f(s)|$ for all $s \in Q$ and $s \neq s_0$
>   if and only if  $$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\| f + tg \| - \| f
>  \|}{t}$$ exists for all $g \in C(Q).$

Proof:

Suppose that $\| f \|_{\infty} = |f(s_0)|$ and $\| f \|_{\infty} > |f(s)|$ for all $s \in Q$ and $s \neq s_0.$
Let $g \in C(Q)$ and a real number $t.$
Since $g$ is continuous on $Q$, we have $f + tg$ is also continuous on $Q.$ 
By the Extreme Value Theorem, there exists $s_t \in Q$ such that $\| f+tg \|_{\infty} = |(f+tg)(s_t)| = |f(s_t) +tg(s_t)|.$
Observe that 
$$|f(s_0) + tg(s_0)| - |f(s_0)| \leq \| f + tg\|_{\infty} - \| f \|_{\infty} = |f(s_t) + tg(s_t)| - |f(s_0)|.$$
It follows that 
$$|f(s_0) + tg(s_0)| \leq |f(s_t) + tg(s_t)|.$$
By triangle inequality and reverse triangle inequality, we have 
$$0 < |f(s_0)| - |f(s_t)| \leq |t| \cdot (|g(s_t)| + |g(s_0)|) \leq 2|t|\cdot \| g\|_{\infty}.$$
Since $\| g \|_{\infty}$ is finite, by Squeeze Theorem, we have 
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} |f(s_t)| = |f(s_0)|.$$
**By compactness of $Q$, we have 
$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}s_t = s_0. $**

> Question: How does compactness lead to $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}s_t = s_0 $?

I thought the limit is due to continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\{s_t\}$ is an infinite set. By compactness of $Q$, it has a limit point $s$. Take a sequence $s_{t_n}$ converging to $s$. By continuity of $f$,
$f(s)=f(s_0)$. If $s\neq s_0$, then $|f(s_0)|>|f(s)|$ by the above. Therefore $s=s_0$.

Comment: When I saw $\lim_{t\to 0}s_t=s_0$ in the Q my eyebrows went up. There are  compact Hausdorff spaces that are not sequential spaces. There are infinite compact Hausdorff spaces where the  only convergent sequences are eventually-constant sequences.